# Java 8 Calculate minimum value

Tags: java, java-8

I am practicing with Java 8. I don't understand why this method always return 0, or better the identity value:

```
public static Integer getMinAge(List<Person> peopleList) {
    return peopleList.stream().mapToInt(Person::getAge).reduce(0, Integer::min);
}
```

Surprisingly, the Integer::max method returns the correct value. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because you provided the identity value of zero, you apply the function Integer.min, and you don't have any negative ages, logically, so zero is always the lowest value?! Try `reduce(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer::min)`

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use `.reduce(Integer::min)` or even `.min()` instead, but those methods return an OptionalInt - because without the provided identity value, there may be no result (if the stream is empty!)

Comment: Even better! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because `age > 0 and identity == 0` then `Integer.min(identity,age)` always return 0.

### use IntStream.reduce(IntBinaryOperator)

```
public static Integer getMinAge(List<Person> peopleList) {
  return peopleList.stream().mapToInt(Person::getAge)
            .reduce(Integer::min).orElse(0);
}
```

### use IntStream.min()

```
public static Integer getMinAge(List<Person> peopleList) {
  return peopleList.stream().mapToInt(Person::getAge)
           .min().orElse(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The question has already been answered in the comments, but I do not think that the minimum age of zero people should be `0`, or `Integer.MAX_INT`. I prefer:

```
public static Integer getMinAge(List<Person> peopleList) {
    return peopleList.stream().mapToInt(Person::getAge).min().getAsInt();
}
```

`min()` is the most concise solution and it forces you to think about the corner case of an empty stream. In your case, I'd treat it as a programmer error and throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Because you called `reduce(0, Integer::min)`, 0 itself is the smallest number among people's age list. You can refer to [java doc of IntStream.recude](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) for more details. If you need to find the youngest people, you need call it like `reduce(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer::min)`

Comment: Careful; if the stream happens to be empty, it will return `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is kind of unexpected.